# Amazon S3 Static website hosting support both trailing slash and not

Tags: amazon-s3

In Django, for example, you can turn on a feature that will redirect a url to its trailing-slash counterpart if the URL doesn't resolve. There are also add-ons that accomplish the reverse.

Is there any way to get S3 to do something similar? Where I can have both  .com/page  and .com/page/ resolve (or redirect) to the page object in my bucket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default a request for `example.com/page` will redirect to `example.com/page/` if `page` isn't an object in your bucket and `page/index.html` (or whatever you've got the index document set to) is.

You could also get it to work in the opposite direction by setting the `x-amz-redirect` header on `page/index.html` back to `http://example.com/page`, though that's a bit more complicated.

Comment: Is there a way to turn this behavior off?

Comment: I'm not sure, they've added a lot of options to the website config so you should check those docs. Worst case you could emulate it by copying your 404 page to `<key>` wherever `<key>/<index-document>` exists and there isn't already an object at `<key>`.